# DataGridView not displaying column headers correctly at design time

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have observed some odd behaviour when working with the DataGridView inside a GroupBox. I understand that the DataGridView uses Ambient properties which inherit styles as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0(v=vs.110).aspx), however, I do believe there is a bug when displaying in design time. Here are the steps to recreate in Visual Studio 2013 (I also did this in VS2008 with the same results):

Create a new form. Create a GroupBox and set the font size to 22. Create a DataGridView inside the Group box and add three columns (all default settings).

The DataGridView column headers will inherit the GroupBox font settings as expected:

[image]

Change the `DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles` to property to `False` and edit the `DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`. Set the `Font` to be `Mistral, 9.75pt`. The form should now look like this in design view and when you run the application:

[image]

Now the fun starts. Save and close the Form1 tab and re-open it by double clicking the form in the Solution Explorer. Now in design view, the column header has changed and is seemingly inheriting the font setting of the parent GroupBox:

[image]

However when the application is run, the headers use the correct font settings:

[image]

Is this a bug with the design view rendering or am I misunderstanding the inheritance rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly seems like a bug with the designer. I see the same effect in VS2013, even though the `Designer.cs` file retains the following line:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Mistral", 9.75F,
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

I'm not sure why a control inside the `GroupBox` behaves that way, but there is a workaround.

Place a `Panel` inside the `GroupBox`, then place controls such as the `DataGridView` in the `Panel`.

Then you can set the `Font` property on the `Panel` and have it inherited by the `DataGridView`, or you can just change the header style on the grid and it will still display correctly after closing / reopening the `Form`.